# can an app be auto-update when is still open?

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

i dont know if this question sound familiar but im been searching and i couldn't find a stray anwer yet (this is what google say about auto-update https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en). in my specific case the app im developing is intented to be always running, but it also need to be up to date... so i publish it in the google play store but i have some troubles with the auto-update, im doing my own test but the store is not quite as fast as we would like... long story short can be the app auto-update when is still running?

Comment: It depends on what you exactly want to update: data, ui, business logic.

Comment: i was refering to an update of the apk in general

Comment: an updated  version (1 to 2 or somehting like that)

Comment: Apk file could be changed (replaced) by `adb` tool or `PlayStore` app. So I suppose answer on your question is no - app can't be auto-updated.

Comment: if my app is plublish in the PlayStore and i upload another vesion, and the user have the auto-update active, can the running app make that update or it need to be close so the PlayStore make the auto-update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important bits:

> Google Play Store can take hours / days to get your update to a user, and, unfortunately, you can't force an app to update itself.
>
> You can find an official answer from Google here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055196#ts=3055315,3055203
>
> As an alternative, you can check the [Alternative Distribution Options](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html) from the Android Developers documentation, if you want to personally take care of the distribution process of your app.

As Fox-In-Socks notes, only the Play Store app can replace the APK on any user's device. Because the userbase of Android is so big, the distribution of a new APK can take hours, if not days, to reach all your users. They even note that when you upload a new version of your app in the Google Play Developers Console.

Also, take into account that not every android user has Auto-Update turned on in their devices and that every time an app is updated, it is stopped and then restarted, so the "always on" assumption for an app is broken for a couple of seconds when it is updated.

Comment: but the app can be update it when is still running regardless the time the PlayStore can take and the couple of secounds that take to update it?

Comment: Yes, even if you do it manually, you can update an app while it's running. It will stop for that couple of seconds, but it will restart once the update has been completed.

Comment: im gonna run somo more test but thanks  (i just need a little more patience with the store)